# How to change the URL on menu selection?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, topmenu, submenu

Iam working on magento 1.9 theme

1. When i make a menu selection of " Jewellery " , the url shown is http://192.168.1.99/in/index.php/sports.html
   instead of
   http://192.168.1.99/in/index.php/jewellery.html
2. The case is same while selecting submenus also, its shown as http://192.168.1.99/in/index.php/sports/submenu.html

Can anyone tell me from where i can make the corresponding changes, so that each menu when selected will give their respective URL.

Answer (score 0):

URLs not working. Please share working URLs.

1. If you are using multiple store. So, please check store wise category URL.
2. Also check "URL Rewrite management".